# How to check if an application is installed on multiple server - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$comps = get-content C:\xyz\test.txt
foreach($comp in $comps)
{
$result = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $comp | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -match “abc”}
$result | out-file -Append out.txt
}
```

There is a application abc , im looking to know whether this is installed in multiple servers.

Comment: In what way does the code you posted not do what you're expecting it to?

Comment: Be careful with `Win32_Product` calling it verifies/repairs every installed msi. So at the very least it's slow and process intensive.

Comment: Please suggest any other alternatives..

Comment: `Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $a | sort-object Name | select Name ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Check this "Hey Scripting Guy" [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/). This link describes how to query for installed applications via the registry.

From the [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/):

> Win32_Product: The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly
> [Good] The Win32_Product WMI class represents products as they are installed >by Windows Installer.
>
> If you choose to query Win32_Product class by using Get-WmiObject, you’ll find >yourself [Bad] waiting for your query (or application) to return [Ugly] a >consistency check of packages that are installed as it attempts to verify and >repair installs. (For more information, see Event log message indicates that >the Windows Installer reconfigured all installed applications).
> ...

Based on above link you can query your installed products via:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Additionally you can use `Test-Path` to check if a requested registry entry exists. Example:

```
if (test-path HKLM:\Software\abc) { write-host "Found" } else { Write-Host "Not found" }
```

To check for installed software on multiple servers:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\xyz\servers.txt
$results = @()
foreach ($server in $servers) {
   $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential (Get-Credential)
   $results += Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
      test-path HKLM:\Software\abc
   }
} 

$results.GetType() # Dump type
$results | gm # Dump properties

$results | Format-Table
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there  any best alternative rather then using wmi.. can we get this from registry ?

Comment: Yes, I've added a one-liner in my above answer.

Comment: My application is under HKLM\Software\abc ..  i want to that abc under Software ..pls help

Comment: I`ve updated my answer. You can use `Test-Path` to check if the registry entry exists or not.

Comment: How can i iterate for multiple servers?
`$t = Get-Content c:\temp\t.txt
foreach($a in $t)
{
if (test-path HKLM:\Software\abc) { write-host "Found" } else { Write-Host "Not found" }

}`

Comment: Extended my answer.

Comment: I dont think its good idea if it ask credentials for multipile servers everytime

Comment: It's up to you. You can also serialize a credential object to a file and reuse it.